# Disable splashscreen on Phonegap 6.3

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to disable the splashcreen in my Phonegap 6.3 app. In the main `config.xml` file, I removed the line that loads the splash screen plugin:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
```

and I removed all the lines that contained

```
<splash density="..." src="www/res/screen/..." />
```

But I still have a splashcreen despite these removals, even after relaunching the server with `phonegap serve`.

I know it is possible to solve the issue using

```
cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", [])
```

but I am trying to understand why removing the plugin declaration does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the documentation [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html#preferences), you might want to try adding this to your `config.xml`.

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you sir !

Comment: If you are testing in-browser with the PhoneGap Desktop application, be sure to stop and restart the server to pick up this change...it didn't seem to take effect by just reloading the page in the browser.

Comment: I still see the PhoneGap splash on iOS emulator